# Custom user service doesn't work with Facebook as external login provider in Identity Server v3

Tags: oauth, identityserver3, identityserver4, facebook-oauth

I have downloaded **Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook** package in order to be able to integrate Facebook as external login provider. I have added it to the app builder as follows:

```
var fbOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AuthenticationType = "Facebook",
    Caption = "Facebook",
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
    AppId = "17*****************5",
    AppSecret = "3a*****************************16",
    Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    },
};

app.UseFacebookAuthentication(fbOptions);
```

And, of course, in https://developers.facebook.com I have registered my app in order to obtain App ID and App secret. I have registred the custom user service in the standart way:

```
public class CustomUserService : UserServiceBase
{
        ....
        // gets called whenever the user uses external identity provider to authenticate
        // now we will try to map external user to a local user
        public override Task AuthenticateExternalAsync(ExternalAuthenticationContext context)
        .... 
}
```

And then in Startup.cs:

```
// use custom user service
var customUserService = new CustomUserService();
idServerServiceFactory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(resolver => customUserService);
```

In the login screen I have Facebook as an option. I can select it, I can navigate to it and successfully enter my credentials. The problem happens right after I get back from Facebook to my Identity Server 3 implementation.

The message in the browser is:

```
There was an error logging into the external provider. The error message is: access_denied
```

Browser url is:

```
https://localhost:44317/identity/callback?error=access_denied#_=_
```

And the one from the logs:

```
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2017-12-07 17:44:26.687 +02:00 [Information] User is not authenticated. Redirecting to login.
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2017-12-07 17:44:26.694 +02:00 [Information] End authorize request
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2017-12-07 17:44:26.701 +02:00 [Information] Redirecting to login page
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2017-12-07 17:44:26.796 +02:00 [Information] Login page requested
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2017-12-07 17:44:26.834 +02:00 [Information] rendering login page
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2017-12-07 17:44:28.425 +02:00 [Information] External login requested for provider: "Facebook"
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2017-12-07 17:44:28.427 +02:00 [Information] Triggering challenge for external identity provider
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2017-12-07 17:44:49.508 +02:00 [Information] Callback invoked from external identity provider
iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : 2017-12-07 17:44:49.508 +02:00 [Error] External identity provider returned error: "access_denied"
```

**NOTE**: I never hit a breakpoint inside of

```
public override Task AuthenticateExternalAsync(ExternalAuthenticationContext context)
```

If it is going to help, I am running the instance of Identity Sever 3 on localhost.

Except for that, when using Fiddler I an see that a call was made to Host: **graph.facebook.com** and it was successful.

```
{"access_token":"EAAYxR1NxxxMBAHLOW17nfS2xTDqXgIU3FY5ZBpw8EJFfzpoQpS5H6eVjsda2ZAN6ABLGu2а21fGleam8LbhPJTZCh8vBdbnQaijEZAwAQqGDyIZCXhR3twL3Fnq1gZBT8zUsPshZBjTFJ9tU0mWb6s8Up4sX9dUdQDCFefqEf4XKZBEZBHmshm","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":5181406}
```

But right after that, a failure happens on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in my case was to update the following nuget packages:

```
Microsoft.Owin
Microsoft.Owin.Security
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google
```

From my current version (**3.0.1**) to version **3.1.0**.

In this way I started hitting the endpoints on my Identity Server instances and it looks good so far.